# Is it possible to fix SlickGrid's column-resizing bug?

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I've recently (re-)discovered SlickGrid, and am considering using it for a project I'm working on, mainly because in many ways it appears to be the most versatile and powerful and performant (forgive the neologism) JavaScript grid yet created.

There are only a few problems.  The first is that it very annoyingly doesn't resize its columns the way users expect: at the same time that they resize the column header.  Many would be quick to point out that this has no practical implication, but I value usability and elegance greatly, and this damages both.

As far as usability, the first time I tried to resize a column I really thought it was not working.  Undoubtedly others will be confused as well.

As far as elegance, it just completely breaks the sense of actually physically manipulating objects.

I don't actually need all the power that SlickGrid gives for this current project, but if its weaknesses can be overcome I see no reason not to use it for everything when I need a grid.  In most respects it is extremely impressive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting the `syncColumnCellResize` option when initialising the grid forces the grid to resize the columns synchronously as the user resizes the column header.

```
var grid;
var columns = [ ... columns stuff
var options = { ... other options,
                syncColumnCellResize: true
              };

var data = [ ... data stuff

grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
```